# Searchanalytics Query JAVA API v3 (Google WebMaster Tools)

Tags: java, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

I am trying to implement **Google  Webmasters Searchanalytics** **Query** using  using the Java API  but i did not found any **Java sample** to use , in Google website [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/libraries) there is only Python samples for Searchanalytics Query , and they did not say that it's not available in Java API.

I found this class [Webmasters.Searchanalytics.Query](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/webmasters/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/webmasters/Webmasters.Searchanalytics.Query.html) in the Java API which I assume that is equivalent to the Python function `searchanalytics.query()` but i did not found any implementation of it.
My question if it is possible to query data from Google Search Console  using the Java API??
if yes i wounder if there is someone who can provide a Java sample, something like the Python sample provided by Google [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/searchconsole/search_analytics_api_sample.py).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeded to implement [Webmasters.Searchanalytics.Query](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/webmasters/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/webmasters/Webmasters.Searchanalytics.Query.html) 
as follow

first you need to create your QueryRequest using the **SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest** class example:

```
private static SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest createSearchAnalyticsQueryRequest() {
        SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest searQueryRequest = new SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
        searQueryRequest.setStartDate("2016-04-10");
        searQueryRequest.setEndDate("2016-04-20");
        List<String> dimensions = new ArrayList<String>();
        dimensions.add("page");
        dimensions.add("query");
        dimensions.add("country");
        dimensions.add("device");
        dimensions.add("date");
        searQueryRequest.setDimensions(dimensions);
        return searQueryRequest;
    }
```

then executing the query as follow :

```
public static String Query(String site,
            SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest searQueryRequest) throws Exception {

        Webmasters.Searchanalytics.Query query = service.searchanalytics()
                .query(site, searQueryRequest);
        SearchAnalyticsQueryResponse queryResponse = query.execute();

        return queryResponse.toPrettyString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You missed it. [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/quickstart/quickstart-java#step_1_enable_the_search_console_api). Actually all you need to do is to click the `Java` link on the left.

Comment: no i did not miss it , what i need is the java implementation of ' the Query your Google Search data '   here  https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/how-tos/search_analytics